# postfix sending mail TLS library problem: error:0A00010B:SSL routines::wrong version number:../ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:354:

Tags: linux, ssl, postfix-mta

I am trying to set up postfix to send and receive mail on Ubuntu 22.04.2, using postfix/jammy-updates,now 3.6.4-1ubuntu1.1.

The error I get is in the title:
TLS library problem: error:0A00010B:SSL routines::wrong version number:../ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:354:

I get this both from yahoo mail, gmail and others.

My main.cf and master.cf files are below. I'm afraid they are a patchwork of advice I collected on the internet trying to fix earlier problems.

Thanks,

Geza

```
compatibility_level = 3.6
command_directory = /usr/sbin
daemon_directory = /usr/lib/postfix/sbin
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
myhostname = mydomain.com
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
debug_peer_level = 1
debug_peer_list = 127.0.0.1
debugger_command = 
     PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin; export PATH; ( /usr/bin/strace -p $process_id 2>&1 | logger -p mail.err ) & sleep 5
inet_protocols = ipv4
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = mydomain.com, localhost
sender_canonical_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sender_canonical
relayhost = 
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = no
allow_mail_to_commands = alias
allow_mail_to_files = alias
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
inet_interfaces = all
mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
mailbox_size_limit = 0
masquerade_domains = mydomain.com
recipient_delimiter = +
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_mechanism_filter = plain, login, cram-md5
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl/pass
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_sasl_type = cyrus
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/postfix/ca-certificates.crt
smtp_tls_mandatory_ciphers    = high
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtp_tls_security_level = encrypt
smtp_tls_wrappermode = yes
smtpd_data_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated,permit_mynetworks,reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $myhostname
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous,noplaintext
smtpd_sasl_tls_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/cert.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix/key.pem
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 4
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = >=TLSv1.2
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_use_tls = yes
smtp_use_tls = yes
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
tls_medium_cipherlist = TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA:TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA:TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA:TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA:TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA:TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256:TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA:TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
```

and

```
smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
tlsproxy  unix  -       -       n       -       0       tlsproxy
submission inet n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject


pickup    unix  n       -       n       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       y       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       y       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       y       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       y       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       y       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
        -o syslog_name=postfix/$service_name
showq     unix  n       -       y       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       y       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       y       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       y       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       y       -       1       scache
postlog   unix-dgram n  -       n       -       1       postlogd

relay-smtps  unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
         -o smtp_tls_security_level=encrypt
         -o smtp_tls_wrappermode=yes

uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix -       n       n       -       2       pipe
  flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=FRX user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py ${nexthop} ${user}


smtps     inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
```

Comment: If you are up to date, wrong version typically means you are expecting ssl and the server is  not encrypting.